# DataSourceRequest adding attributes to a grid view kendo

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datagridview

hello i'm developping an application with asp.net mvc 4  and i'm using kendo to add DataGridView !
i have some troubles :

i wanna add two attributes to a column in a datagridview

i have a model "user" and a model "project" 
when the user create new project i have to add his name and family name to the datagridview 
this is my interface :

[[image: 1]]

this is my controller :

```js
 public ActionResult Projet_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var projets = (from a in db.Projets
                          join b in db.Utilisateurs on a.UtilisateurID equals b.UtilisateurID
                          select new 
                          { 
                              ProjetId=a.ProjetId,
                              nomP=a.nomP,
                              DateDebut=a.DateDebut,
                              DateFinPrevue=a.DateFinPrevue,
                              DateFinReele=a.DateFinReele,
                              etat=a.etat,
                              Description=a.Description,
                              U=b.Prenom // U=b.Prenom +" "+b.Nom
                          });
            DataSourceResult result = projets.ToDataSourceResult(request, projet1 => new
            {
                ProjetId = projet1.ProjetId,
                nomP = projet1.nomP,
                DateDebut = projet1.DateDebut,
                DateFinPrevue = projet1.DateFinPrevue,
                DateFinReele = projet1.DateFinReele,
                Description = projet1.Description,
                etat = projet1.etat,
                U=projet1.U
            });
             return Json(result);
        }
```

This is my view :

```js
<legend class="legend">Tous Les Projets</legend>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid placeholders">
    <div style="height:850px">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<mvc_depences.Models.Projet>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.U).Title("Chef de Projet").Width(145);
            columns.Bound(c => c.nomP).Title("Nom Projet");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateDebut).Title("Date Debut");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateFinPrevue).Title("Date Fin Prevue");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateFinReele).Title("Date Fin Réelle");
            columns.Bound(c => c.etat).Title("Etat");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title("Description");
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Modifier"); }).Width(150);   
        })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
      .Pageable()
      .Selectable(selectable =>
      {
          selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
          selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
      })
      .Filterable()
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProjetId))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Projet_Read", "Projet"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Projet_Update", "Projet"))
      )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is not working ?

Comment: instead of showing just the user's name i wanna show his family name :  my code now : U=b.Prenom  and that's what i tried U=b.Prenom +" "+b.Nom       --> i wana do a concat and add it to the grid view ! it is possible ?

Comment: no ! it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've no experience with Kendo UI. My guess is that you try to concatenate string inside of SQL query. You could try to get *all* data first (including both first and last name) and map them in your view.

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Projet_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var projets = (from a in db.Projets
                          join b in db.Utilisateurs on a.UtilisateurID equals b.UtilisateurID
                          select new 
                          { 
                              ProjetId = a.ProjetId,
                              nomP = a.nomP,
                              DateDebut = a.DateDebut,
                              DateFinPrevue = a.DateFinPrevue,
                              DateFinReele = a.DateFinReele,
                              etat = a.etat,
                              Description = a.Description,
                              Prenom = b.Prenom,
                              Nom = b.Nom
                          });
            DataSourceResult result = projets.ToDataSourceResult(request, projet1 => new
            {
                ProjetId = projet1.ProjetId,
                nomP = projet1.nomP,
                DateDebut = projet1.DateDebut,
                DateFinPrevue = projet1.DateFinPrevue,
                DateFinReele = projet1.DateFinReele,
                Description = projet1.Description,
                etat = projet1.etat,
                Prenom = projet1.Prenom,
                Nom = projet1.Nom
            });
             return Json(result);
        }
```

In View :

```
<legend class="legend">Tous Les Projets</legend>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid placeholders">
    <div style="height:850px">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<mvc_depences.Models.Projet>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => String.Format("{0} {1}", c.Prenom, c.Nom)).Title("Chef de Projet").Width(145);
            columns.Bound(c => c.nomP).Title("Nom Projet");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateDebut).Title("Date Debut");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateFinPrevue).Title("Date Fin Prevue");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateFinReele).Title("Date Fin Réelle");
            columns.Bound(c => c.etat).Title("Etat");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title("Description");
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Modifier"); }).Width(150);   
        })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
      .Pageable()
      .Selectable(selectable =>
      {
          selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
          selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
      })
      .Filterable()
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProjetId))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Projet_Read", "Projet"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Projet_Update", "Projet"))
      )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

This should do the trick

Comment: when i put Prenom = projet1.Prenom, Nom = projet1.Nom in the sql request i doesn't show me any error but when i try to put it in the DataSourceResult result it marks it in red and this is the message : " Error 2 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Prenom' and no extension method 'Prenom' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\NAD-info\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mvc_depences\mvc_depences\mvc_depences\Controllers\ProjetController.cs 102 34 mvc_depences
  "

Comment: @kokomoi That's great. But was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

i just did the concatenation in the sql request and i left the other code unchanged !

```html
public ActionResult Projet_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var projets = (from a in db.Projets
                          join b in db.Utilisateurs on a.UtilisateurID equals b.UtilisateurID
                          select new 
                          { 
                              ProjetId=a.ProjetId,
                              nomP=a.nomP,
                              DateDebut=a.DateDebut,
                              DateFinPrevue=a.DateFinPrevue,
                              DateFinReele=a.DateFinReele,
                              etat=a.etat,
                              Description=a.Description,
                              U=b.Prenom +" "+ b.nom
                          });
            DataSourceResult result = projets.ToDataSourceResult(request, projet1 => new
            {
                ProjetId = projet1.ProjetId,
                nomP = projet1.nomP,
                DateDebut = projet1.DateDebut,
                DateFinPrevue = projet1.DateFinPrevue,
                DateFinReele = projet1.DateFinReele,
                Description = projet1.Description,
                etat = projet1.etat,
                U=projet1.U,
            });
             return Json(result);
        }
```